# How to change colors and font of treemap labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change the color of the labels on the darkest rectangles of my treemap to white to increase readability. Is there a way to do this? I also would like to change the font of my labels. Ideally I would like the font to match the base R default font (I'm not sure what that font is called?). Is there a way to change the label fonts?

```
# Creating Dataframe 
 subgroup <-c()
 df<- data.frame(Fruits=c("Owners' Equivalent Rent of Residences", 
                     "Rent of Primary Residence",
                     "New Vehicles", 
                    
    "Motor Vehicle Insurance",
                     "Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair",
                    
                     "Apparel", 
                     "Medical Care Commodities",
                     "Alcoholic Beverages", 
                     "Hospital Services",
                     "Tobacco and Smoking",
                     "Physicians Services",
                     "Gasoline All Types",
                     "Electricity", 
                    
                    
                     "Food Away From Home", 
                     "Meats Poultry Fish and Eggs", 
                     "Fruits and Vegetables", 
                     "Dairy and Related Products",
                     "Cereals And Bakery Products", 
                     "Other Foods at Home"), 
            perc=c(6.7, 6.9, 1.3, 19.2, 8.5, 1.1, 5, 2.9, 
                   6.3, 7.7, 0.7, -8.9, 3.4, 5.3, 0.1, 0.4, 
                   -1.4, 3.4, 3.3)) 
 library(ggplot2)
 library(treemapify)

 pal_fill <- colorRampPalette(scales::brewer_pal(palette = "Reds")(9))
 pal_fill <- pal_fill(length(unique(df$Fruits)))
 names(pal_fill) <- levels(reorder(df$Fruits, df$perc))

 ggplot(df, aes(area = perc, fill = Fruits, label = Fruits)) +
  geom_treemap(layout = "squarified") +
  geom_treemap_text(
   aes(label = paste0(Fruits, "\n", perc, "%")),
 place = "centre", size = 12
  ) +
 scale_fill_manual(values = pal_fill) +
 labs(title = "Categories Contributing Most to Inflation in 2023") +
 guides(fill = "none")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of changing the font family check out `?graphics::par` in relation to the `family` argument where it mentions  the following:

*The name of a font family for drawing text. ... The default value is "" which means that the default device fonts will be used (and what those are should be listed on the help page for the device)*

Therefore in base R, the default font used for plots and graphics is system-dependent, as it relies on the standard fonts available and default settings of the operating system on which R is running.

Depending on your OS check the availiable fonts using:

```r
windowsFonts()
X11Fonts()
quartzFonts()
```

In your case you can change the font family using the argument `family` in `treemapify::geom_treemap_text` and `ggplot2::element_text` in the argument `text` inside `ggplot2::theme`. For example using `serif` and `mono`:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(area = perc, fill = Fruits, label = Fruits)) +
  geom_treemap(layout = "squarified") +
  geom_treemap_text(
    aes(label = paste0(Fruits, "\n", perc, "%")),
    place = "centre", size = 12, family = "serif"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal_fill) +
  labs(title = "Categories Contributing Most to Inflation in 2023") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "mono"))
```

Also there is the package [`systemfonts`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=systemfonts) that provides system native access to the font catalogue where using the function `systemsfonts::system_fonts()` you obtain the fonts installed on your system.

To load the fonts you need to use the package [`extrafont`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=extrafont). See more information [here](https://github.com/wch/extrafont) to get started with the package.

For example in your case I was able to obtain the following result using `Bahnschrift` and `Calibri`:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(area = perc, fill = Fruits, label = Fruits)) +
  geom_treemap(layout = "squarified") +
  geom_treemap_text(
    aes(label = paste0(Fruits, "\n", perc, "%")),
    place = "centre", size = 12, family = "Bahnschrift"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal_fill) +
  labs(title = "Categories Contributing Most to Inflation in 2023") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Calibri"))
```

[image]